# Vulkan fails to load layer library

Tags: c, macos, vulkan, apple-silicon, moltenvk

I am using MoltenVK on MacBook Air with Apple Silicon. I have set my environment according to instructions on [Vulkan Tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Development_environment#page_MacOS) website but when I try to run my program in Xcode I get the following two error messages from validation layer:

```
ERROR (Callback: Validation Layer): Loading layer library /usr/local/share/vulkan/explicit_layer.d/../../../lib/libVkLayer_api_dump.dylib
ERROR (Callback: Validation Layer): Loading layer library /usr/local/share/vulkan/explicit_layer.d/../../../lib/libVkLayer_khronos_validation.dylib
```

I have played around with the settings in `vkconfig` and added environment variable `VK_INSTANCE_LAYERS` pointing to list of those two layers that failed to load and `VK_LAYER_PATH` that points to path `/Users/jakub/VulkanSDK/1.3.224.1/macOS/share/vulkan/explicit_layer.d`. None of that worked.

Comment: Does the `explicit_layer.d` directory contain a suitable json file?

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes, it does contain both `VkLayer_api_dump.json` and `VkLayer_khronos_validation.json` files.

Comment: And as for the content of the json files, do the libraries (the .dylib files) that the json files reference exist at the referenced location?

Comment: @KerrekSB Both `libVkLayer_api_dump.dylib` and `libVkLayer_khronos_validation.dylib` also exist at locations specified in relevant .json files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those environment variables only work on macOS if you launch the apps from the command line. Apple does not allow environment variables to be set for GUI apps launched from the desktop, etc. A better way to use layers on macOS is to use VKConfig. You can create a configuration with the layers you want (and there's a nice GUI for tweaking layer parameters). This creates a "metalayer" that the loader will always see and make use without the need for environment variables. Also, make sure you do not link statically to MoltenVK, as this does not use the actual loader and layers will not work (although linking statically is perfectly fine for shipping your apps).

Comment: Using the VkConfig applet helped me with this problem. As for the statically linking with MoltenVK part - I am using GLFW so linking statically with MoltenVK is not even an option as that would override GLFW. Thanks a ton.